# Keyboard Switcher-Does Not Display on Navigation Bar

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, keyboard, navigation

I have the Nexus 9 and the HTC folio keyboard.  I cannot get the keyboard switcher to display in the navigation bar.  I have checked the settings for apps and both Google keyboard and Swiftkey apps are enabled and the notifications boxes are ticked. I want to display the switcher so that can turn off the folio keyboard which is a battery hog.

Answer (score 2):

things have changed a bit in Lollipop. On the Nexus 6, for example, there's a new softkey you can use to change keyboards.

[image]

Comment: I only have this icon when the device keyboard is activaated. And even when this does display it doesn't show the Folio keyboard.  I a looking for an easy way to turn the keyboard on and off.

Answer (score 0):

was the Keyboard activated through the app? 
you should be able activate the keyboard through the app.
alternatively, you can go to:
settings.
language and Input.
and select, selector Icon.
or in the Language and Input menu Choose you keyboard.